# Extreme Learning Machine installation and usage

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to use this python package https://github.com/5663015/elm. I am using anaconda and jupyter notebook. I am not able to install this package using conda. However, for using the package, in the github they say that I should "Download source code, enter cmd in the project directory, run the following command: import elm". Can someone please let me know how I can do this using anaconda and jupyter notebook.

Comment: As it says in the README you linked: `pip install git+https://github.com/masaponto/python-elm`.  This assumes you are in your terminal/command line.  In a jupyter notebook you can run the same command by simply putting an exclamation point at the beginning: `!pip install git+https://github.com/masaponto/python-elm`  (If you have multiple python versions installed, you may need to use `pip3` instead of just `pip`

Comment: @Damian Satterthwaite-Phillips thanks for your answer. Sorry, I put wrong github in the question. I editedd it. I need this package https://github.com/5663015/elm.

Comment: That one is a bit more involved.  You need to clone (copy) the github repository to your local computer: `git clone https://github.com/5663015/elm.git`, then move into that folder (`cd elm`), and from inside that folder run `python setup.py install`, which will build the code on your machine.  If that build is successful you should be able to use `import elm` in your code.